# Is postMessage() supported in InternetExplorer 7?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm testing my code in using IE9 which lets me also test IE8 and IE7 using the developer tool. It seems that postMessage works when testing in the IE7 mode.

I think postMessage should not work in IE7 but my test says it does and I think it's because I'm using IE9 to do the test.

Is IE7 supposed to support postMessage at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; [only IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging). (and even there not across tabs or windows)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting `Document Mode` to IE7, not `Browser Mode`.

Answer (score 1):

For IE, PostMessages is supported only IE8 and above.